# Регулярное выражение в Java типа [ Число1 + Число2 ]

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать Java недавно, по этому сам не справлюсь. Помогите сделать регулярное выражение, которое нужно будет сравнить со строкой, и проверить, есть ли там совпадение с (Число1 + число2). Если есть - вытащить эти числа. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```
 public static void checkWithRegExp(String str){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\+(\\d+)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Совпадение обнаружено!");
            for(int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Число: " + m.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Совпадений не обнаружено!");
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        checkWithRegExp("3+2342");
}
```

В случае параметра `"3+2342"` вывод будет

> Совпадение обнаружено!
>
> Число: 3
>
> Число: 2342

в случае `"31230+"` вывод будет

> Совпадений не обнаружено!

Comment: @SamyRed, если ответ вам помог, не забудьте его принять (зеленая галочка под кнопками голосования)